# Does Vim have an auto-comment feature based on the file's syntax?

Tags: vim, syntax, autocomplete, comments

I'm not sure this is possible, but I'm interesting in making this happen.
Ideally, I would like to map this feature to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

I'm looking for a way to have Vim enter a comment (single line) which corresponds to the syntax of the file I'm editing. If there are multiple single-line comment styles, Vim could either automatically pick one, or give me the choice. If the single-line comment has two parts (e.g. `/*` and `*/`), then pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> the first time will start the comment, and the second time will close the comment.

**Examples:**

- Python: `#`
- JavaScript: `//`
- C, C++: `/*` with `*/` or `//`

I know there are scripts which will insert comments for you, but I haven't seen any that will do this based on the syntax of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of!  I don't believe vim will do this out of the box, but you can install plugins that will do fairly intelligent commenting (using movement keys, visual line highlighting, etc) that are specific to the filetype being edited.  You can get these plugins off of vim.org, and you should be able to make your own key mappings in your .vimrc file if you don't like the ones they come with.

[tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173) is pretty well regarded, and has worked for me.

I've heard that [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) might be better, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks! Both look pretty good. I will try them out sometime today.

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218).

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a similar question to this:
[How to comment in vim while respecting the indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022799/how-to-comment-in-vim-while-respecting-the-indent/)

Use the nerd commenter plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

Comment: Thanks. I will add this to my list of plugins to try.

Answer (score 2):

See: [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Comment_Lines_according_to_a_given_filetype) which provides a function to commented a highlighted area in visual mode.

You want to start a comment in insert mode so your function would look more like:

```
fun CommentLines()
  exe ":s@^@".g:Comment."@g"
endfun
```

Answer (score -1):

Not quite what you're looking for, but efficient, and I suppose you know which comment to use. 
(all this in command mode)
Put your cursor to the first line you want to comment. We willl then set a marker called a (valid names are a-z, single character) by typing

```
ma
```

put the cursor to the last line, then set a marker called b by typing

```
mb
```

Then comment the whole block (by searching for a newline and inserting the comment character (note the use of "#" as search delimiter because otherwise wee have to escape the "/")

```
:'a,'bs#^#//#
```

or for Python:

```
:'a,'bs/^/#/
```

To uncomment:

```
:'a,'bs#^//##
```

As we do line comments, it doesn't matter if we have other comments already in the file, they will be preserved.